# Content of static table view cell not displayed iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm using xcode 7 beta with iPhone 5s (is beta).

I create a table view (static, grouped, 1 section, 3 rows). Rows B and C are basic style and row A is custom with a label.
On my iOS 9 device row A doesn't display any content, but rows B and C are displayed as expected. If I use another device with iOS 8, row A displays the content correctly (my label with text "A").
Other questions here do not match my problem...

What's the Problem with iOS 9?
Or is it a bug?

[image]

[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Your screenshot shows you are working with the size classes "width: compact, height: any" - is your custom static cell definitely configured properly for all size classes (or at least for the size classes you're testing with)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to check Any:Any. In the storyboard the label was displayed correctly and the constraints seemed to be right. But if I removed the constraints and added them again, it worked. @Stuart your comment was very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to reply but I would like to explain what worked for me. I had the same problem `custom cell` was not displaying the content of the `UITableView`.

**Just to check where is the problem:** 
First uncheck Use size classes `checkbox` and run the project, now you are able to see the content in the custom cell. check again the use size classes checkbox and build the project.

**How I fixed:** I was working with size classes "width: compact, height: any". So I checked Any:Any in storyboard for custom cell and fixed the constraints and then again I selected "width: compact, height: any" in storyboard and build the project. Now custom cell is desplaying the content.

**Note:** I am using Xcode 7.3.1